# How Can I change jQuery data handling to Knockout bindings for openWeather API

Tags: json, api, knockout.js, binding

I'd like to use Knockout data binding to update weather API data in my html div element. Currently, I am using jQuery to update the DOM but I prefer to use Knockout. I also want to dynamically change the location zip so weather is specific to that one location in my div. I have an array for locations.

Here's my code:
html:

```js
var zip = locations[0].zipcode;
var myOpenWeatherAPIKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var openWeatherMapUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=" + zip + ",us&APPID=" + myOpenWeatherAPIKey + "&units=imperial";
console.log(zip);
//using JSON method for retrieving API data
$.getJSON(openWeatherMapUrl, function(data) {
    var parameters = $(".weather-data ul");
    var iconCode = data.weather[0].icon;
    var iconDescription = data.weather[0].main;
    var iconUrl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + iconCode + ".png";
    detail = data.main;
    windspd = data.wind;
    parameters.append('<li>Temp: ' + Math.round(detail.temp) + '° F <br></li>');
    parameters.append('<li><img style="width: 25px" src="' + iconUrl + '">  ' + iconDescription + '</li>');
}).fail(weatherError = function(e) {
    $(".weather-data").append("OpenWeatherAPI is unable to load!");
});
```

```html
<div id="open-weather" class="open-weather">
    <div id="weather-data" class="weather-data">
        <p>  <br> Current Weather</p>
        <ul id="weather-items" class="weather-items">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a [custom KO binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) or a [custom KO component](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html) to encapsulate your markup, API keys, jQuery, and XHR calls.

With your code and use case, a component sounds like a good fit. Then your consuming markup could look like

```
<weather params="zip: myZipCode"></weather>
```

where `myZipCode` is a `ko.observable` in your consuming page's view model.

**Update 1**

Added roughed in code for encapsulating inside a KO component.

**Update 2**

Moved jquery DOM references out of KO component code so component template uses KO bindings. Added consuming page view model to show full example.

```js
function openWeatherComponentViewModel(params) {
  var self = this;
  
  self.zip = ko.observable(ko.unwrap(params.zip));
  self.temperature = ko.observable();
  self.iconCode = ko.observable();
  self.iconUrl = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + self.iconCode() + ".png";
  });
  self.iconDescription = ko.observable();
  self.hasWeather = ko.observable(false);
  self.errorMessage = ko.observable();
  
  var apiKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
  var url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=" + self.zip() + ",us&APPID=" + apiKey + "&units=imperial";  
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    self.temperature(Math.round(data.main.temp));
    self.iconCode(data.weather[0].icon);
    self.iconDescription(data.weather[0].main);
    self.hasWeather(true);
  }).fail(function(error) {
    self.hasWeather(false);
    self.errorMessage("OpenWeatherAPI is unable to load! " + error.responseJSON.message);
  });
}

ko.components.register('weather-component', {
  viewModel: openWeatherComponentViewModel,
  template: `<div id="open-weather" class="open-weather">
                <div id="weather-data" class="weather-data" data-bind="if: hasWeather()">
                    <p>Current Weather for Zip Code <span data-bind="text: zip"></span></p>
                    <ul id="weather-items" class="weather-items">
                      <li>Temp: <span data-bind="text: temperature"></span>° F</li>
                      <li><img style="width: 25px" data-bind="attr: { src: iconUrl }"><span data-bind="text: iconDescription"></span></img></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="weather-data" class="weather-data" data-bind="if: !hasWeather()">
                    <span data-bind="text: errorMessage"></span>
                <div>
            </div>`
});

function myConsumingPageViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.myZipCode = ko.observable("80130");
}

var vm = new myConsumingPageViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<weather-component params="zip: myZipCode"></weather-component>
```

Comment: Hi @JoeWilson, I am having hard time coming up with this code. I have `function openWeatherViewModel(params) {
    this.temp = params.temp;
    this.iconCode = params.iconCode;
    this.iconUrl = params.iconUrl;
    this.iconDescription = params.iconDescription;
}

ko.components.register('weather-component', {
    viewModel: openWeatherViewModel,
    template: 'temp: data-bind="value:temp"/><br />\
    iconUrl: data-bind="value:iconUrl"/>>br />'
});

ko.applyBindings();` but not sure how to use API data from json to bind with it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I roughed in the component code above. It doesn't work since I don't have an API key, but once you get inside the API callback, your code should work the same as it did before without using a component. Note the markup has the custom element and a hard-coded zip code.

Comment: I am not getting data to weather div still. Code seems to be using the jquery method still. I need to remove the jquery DOM updates and use knockout template instead. Also, I am getting error  "You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element." I already have another viewmodel in my app.js file. That's the issue. I looked up how to bind multiple viewmodels but doesn't seem to be preferred way. Here's my gitHub repository: https://github.com/ressen1012/neighborhood-map

Comment: Updated answer to move jquery DOM references out of KO component code so component template uses KO bindings. Added consuming page view model to show full example of component code and component consuming code.

Comment: Thank you Joe! When I put the new openWeatherComponentViewModel in my code outside of initMap function I get 2 errors: Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element. and Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "textInput: function (){return query }"
Message: query is not defined. I tried moving it into the existing ViewModel and I get Uncaught ReferenceError: myConsumingPageViewModel is not defined error. I am not exactly sure why.

Comment: Your original question was, "How Can I change jQuery data handling to Knockout bindings for openWeather API". I've explained how to do that. I've written the code to show you how to do that. Now you are asking about how to integrate this code into your app. You should accept this answer and ask a new question.

Comment: Appreciate the help Joe! I am a noobie to Knockout and have had hard time grasping the concept when it came to complex bindings. I managed to get openWeather to work with my current model in my app. I had to create `ko.cleanNode();` before I could apply second viewModel. Also, I binded the second viewModel with jQuery element id `$("#open-weather")[0]`. Thanks again! Res